# Spark Streaming: connection refused

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a simple Spark Streaming code which I want to try:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object WordCountStreamingWithFlume {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("socketstream"), Seconds(10))
    val hostname = "localhost"

    val mystreamRDD = ssc.socketTextStream(hostname, 7777)
    mystreamRDD.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

I'm using `sbt` to compile and package it.

In a console (I'm using Manjaro Linux), I run this: 
`cat file.txt | nc localhost 7777` to send data to the port `7777` in my machine.

To run the compiled Spark Streaming  code, I open the terminal in Intellij IDEA and do the following:

```
spark-submit target/scala-2.11/simplesparkflumeexample_2.11-0.1.jar
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
WARN Utils: Your hostname, ... resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using <some_ip> instead (on interface enp2s0)
WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Error connecting to localhost:7777
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
...
```

I've also tried:

First, check the sshd service, and it was running.

Then, check the 7777 port, and I'm not sure how to confirm this point. The only thing I performed was open two console and send data from one to the other with `netcat`. The result was successful because I could see the data I was typing in a console appear to the other.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remember that not all `nc` implementations have the same syntax. In some you have to provide port as `-p`. Also `-l` is normally required for inbound connections. _Then, check the 7777 port, and I'm not sure how to confirm this point_ - just `telnet`?

Comment: I meant, I've checked with netcat and the 7777 port does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a console (I'm using Manjaro Linux), I run this: cat file.txt | nc localhost 7777 to send data to the port 7777 in my machine.

Instead of run in that way, it worked when I ran doing this (adding `-l` and `-p`):

`cat file.txt | nc -l localhost -p 7777`

Comment: The same behavior with osx Big Sur, I had to use nc -l localhost -p 12346 in order to run a socket server listening in port 12346. It is weird because it should work doing nc -l 12346